# Setting input initial value and update onChange with hook. Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've looked at other similar questions and I can't seem to figure this out. I know with hooks, we want to place them at the top of the component and should avoid placing them in conditionals but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated as I've spent an embarrassingly large amount of time on this. Complete brain meltdown. Thanks so much in advance.

I'm setting the initial value of the input with getData and onChange need to call the hook for setData to update each input. It works initially, then bombs upon later rerenders.

```
const createCustomInputAttrBlock = (
  productId: any, 
  customAttributeName: string, 
  customData: any) => {

  const [getData, setData] = React.useState(customData);

  if (customAttributeName === 'customunits') {
    return (
      <styles.ProductTableCellBorderRight>
        <styles.ProductInputField
          component="bs-input"
          type="input"
          class="product-input-field"
          key={`product-${productId}`}
          name={`product-${productId}`}
          value={getData === '0.0' ? null : getData}
          onChange={(e) => setData(utils.allowDollarChars(e.target.value))}
          />
      </styles.ProductTableCellBorderRight>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <styles.ProductTableCell>
        <styles.ProductInputField
          component="bs-input"
          type="input"
          class="product-input-field"
          key={`product-${productId}`}
          name={`product-${productId}`}
          value={getData === '0.0' ? null : getData}
          onChange={(e) => setData(utils.allowDollarChars(e.target.value))}
          />
      </styles.ProductTableCell>
    );
  }
};
```

This is being called only here further down the file:

````
      <styles.ProductCardDiv colSpan={2} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        {customAttributes === 'customunits' ? (
          createCustomInputAttrBlock(productId, customAttributes, customData)
        ) : (
            <div>Result 1</div>
          )}

        {customAttributes === 'custompoints' ? (
          createCustomInputAttrBlock(productId, customAttributes, customData)
        ) : (
            <div>Result 2</div>
          )}
      </styles.ProductCardDiv>
    </div>```
````

Comment: Are you sure you are not using this component inside some map function? And if yes, did you provide a unique key for each element? I had the same issue for that reason.

Comment: I am. It is however being called in another conditional I'll add above.

Comment: You should make sure that whenever you render an array of elements you put unique keys for each element. Check your console for this type of errors.
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys